# How to use Marketo template meta variable into javascript

Tags: marketo

Is it possible to use the Marketo template variable (eg: **${var}**) in Javascript? **var** is defined with a meta tag inside head.
I am looking for something like this:

```
<meta class="mktoBoolean" id="var" mktoName="Show data" false_value="none" true_value="block">


    if(${show_video_1} === "none") {
        console.log("Hello World")
    }
```

Is this something how it should be done or it needs to have a quotation/backtick?